# Grab all incidents (Cases) from CRM 2011 Into C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I cannot find any tutorial or anything on how to get information from CRM 2011. I need to be able to query CRM and grab all cases / incidents that are not closed.

I am using .Net 4.5 with C# and vs2012.
Does anyone have a guide, tutorial, advice or anything on how I could read cases from CRM 2011?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all download the CRM 2011 SDK,you can find here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004

Inside there are many examples.

You need also to target your projects to .Net 4 (full profile, not client profile)

Comment: In addition articles like these on the MSDN are well worth reading. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328416.aspx